# IOS Swift nested vertical StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Is it a good practice to have nested vertical or horizontal StackViews in my project there is requirement to do so or is there any other way to avoid this or it is okay to use nested vertical StackViews.

Storyboard looks like below it is working fine and UI is appearing as expected across resolution but not sure if it is good practice or not

[image]

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Meanwhile, separate each sentence with the period.  That's basics in English writing.

Comment: okay thanks will keep in mind your advice sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Using multiple StackViews could cause performance downside. If you have checked on real device and it works good, so I don't see any problem either

Answer (score 0):

As always there are Pros and Cons.

Pro:

- Layout structure is easily comprehensive
- You can hide/show groups of views very easily
- Saves time towards doing all things with constraints
- Reordering is a lot easier

Con:

- [Layout performance is worse than constraint layout](https://github.com/layoutBox/LayoutFrameworkBenchmark). If you put a deeply nested layout-structure inside a `UITableViewCell` you could notice frame drops.

So you have to decide or test in your own situation, if you notice any performance issues. 
Maybe use an older device like iPhone 6 or so and try to open your view controller that contains this layout and check if it lags or so.

Comment: It is not a table view cell and there is no scroll as well I guess less chances of performance issues ?

Comment: Yep than you should be fine. You may encounter a split second of a lag when loading this ViewController, but most users won't notice.